# Blazor bUnit 3rd party library with ChildContent

Tags: unit-testing, blazor-server-side, xunit, dbunit, mudblazor

I am new to [bUnit](https://bunit.dev/) and Blazor, so maybe what I want is not possible to achieve, but I am using [MudBlazor](https://www.mudblazor.com/) and I want to check if the ChildContent of my MudDrawer contains a certain parameter.

My razor component is:

```
<MudDrawer @bind-Open="@Open" Elevation="0">
    <MudDrawerHeader>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Edison</MudText>
    </MudDrawerHeader>
    <MyCustomComponent Param1="_myParam1" Param2="_myParam2" />
</MudDrawer>

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool Open { get; set; }

    private string _myParam1 = string.Empty;    
    private Dictionary<string, bool> _myParam2 = [];

    protected override void OnInitialized(){
        _myParam2.Add("Something", true);
    }
}
```

The test I have created so far, using xUnit is:

```
@inherits TestContext

@code{
  [Fact]
  public void ShouldSendCorrectValuesToParameter()
  {
    ComponentFactories.AddStub<MudDrawer>();
    var cut = RenderComponent<MyComponent>(parameters => parameters.Add("Open", true));

    IRenderedComponent<Stub<MudDrawer>> drawerStub = cut.FindComponent<Stub<MudDrawer>>();

    drawerStub.Instance.Parameters.Get(p => p.Open).Should().BeTrue();

    // Here I want to check if MyCustomComponent receives both parameters correctly. Is this possible?
```

My question is: Is it possible to get/create the ChildContent and verify if MyCustomComponent is receiving the correct parameters?

Thank you in advance,